# How to detect GDI resource leaks in managed C# screensaver?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2013, gdi+, resource-leak

Here's my problem ... I suspect a GDI Resource leak in my C# screensaver that uses only managed code. Error: 'Out of memory' after many operations. I compile using VS Prof 2013 Update 4 and run under Windows 7 64bit. I use *Dispose* and non-static routines wherever possible. Here are my issues:

- Being a screensaver, I have not even been able to use the JITdebugger 
  (the application load process just hangs)
- Deleaker is a tool for C++, not C#
- Detailed internet links apply to Windows 9x / Windows 2000 (MSDN Magazine from 2001) or Windows 2000 / Windows XP (also MSDN Magazine)
- can't download GDIObj (apparently unavailable)
- I can display 'GDO Objects' in Task Manager but the screensaver uses the whole screen and overlays it while running
- ... also with GDIview from NirSoft (Explorer.exe strangely has the highest count of GDI objects)

**Thus my questions are ...**

- do developers no longer have GDI resource leaks using Visual Studio C#?
- can GDI+ be used to continually update the screen? (in a simulation app)
- do developers no longer use GDI/GDI+ for 2.5D? (= multi-layer 2D)
- if so, what technology is best suited for a simulation-type application that

  - runs forever (in theory)
  - regularly updates parts within the *whole* screen (text & graphics)
  - runs in real-time (100 msec difference is tolerable but it must keep pace with a radio clock).
  - high resolution graphics (to the pixel in 1920x1080 format), i.e. no low-res gaming use of DirectX; no use of single-precision GPU arithmetic

C# almost worked!

In appreciation of your creative responses...

**UPDATE 1**

I implemented GetGuiResources() in C# as follows (code extract):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class FreeMem
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetGuiResources(IntPtr hProcess, uint uiFlags);

    public static int GetGuiResourcesGDICount()
    {
        return (int)GetGuiResources(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, 0);
    }

    public static int GetGuiResourcesUserCount()
    {
        return (int)GetGuiResources(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, 1);
    }
}
```

and my application showed

- a stable GCIcount between 38 and 42
- a stable UserCount between 18 and 19

until the intentionally (user-) provoked crash *after which* it showed

- GCIcount = 62
- UserCount = 35

i.e. nothing dramatic.

**Please note** that I regularly execute the following on a 1920 x 1080 pixel bitmap:

```
Graphics grTemp = Graphics.FromImage(HighlightedTZ.p_bmpC);
grTemp.DrawImage(DayNight.p_bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, DayNight.p_bmp.Width, DayNight.p_bmp.Height));
grTemp.Dispose();
```

Comment: You could maybe try another tool like Jetbrains dotMemory: https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/

Comment: Actually Deleaker can debug any binary because it just hooks winapi functions. But in the case of C# you will not see correct stack traces. Give it a try, disable all filters so far... At least probably you could find a type of GDI leak: HDC, or HBITMAP, or something else.

Comment: Also are you sure that this is a GDI leak issue? If you can't use Task Manager, take GetGuiResources and dump results periodically http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getguiresources

Comment: try debugdiag: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42933.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second system to remotely debug your C# code.

If you only have one machine available, you can create a second system using a virtual machine system, such as Oracle's free Virtual Box (I recommend this), or some other VM software. You will need a valid Windows license, because even though your VM software is emulating a computer, the new OS will count it as a real computer. If you have an MSDN subscription, then you can get extra OS license keys for debugging and development purposes.

Put your product on that VM, install the Visual Studio remote bugger on the VM, start it up and make sure you can access it from your host machine's Visual Studio (by using attach to process from your host machine's Visual Studio). Now you are ready to remotely debug.

Let your screen saver start on the VM. Once it starts, start up your host VS debugging by attaching to the screen saver using the remote debugger. Now set your breakpoints and watchpoints and debug as normal.

If you have a second windows box available, then you don't need the Virtual Machine software. Just install your product (screen saver) on the second windows machine, install the Visual Studio remote debugging toolset on it, start remote debugger, set it to allow you to access it, start up your preferred machine's Visual Studio, wait for the screen saver to start on second machine, attach from your Visual Studio, set break points, watch items, and debug as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... I don't have a second Windows license. Remote debugging sounds very interesting!